# Emitting value from Setup section in included file

Tags: inno-setup

I have read [in an answer by TLama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20021475/480982) how to emit a setting into a code section so it can be used at runtime. This works as long as it is in one file. However, if I have

test.iss

```
#include "include.iss"
[Setup]
AppId={{87E1AD40-F32B-4EF7-A2FF-5B508814068A}
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program
```

and include.iss

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := '{#SetupSetting("AppId")}';
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

I get an empty message box. The [documentation on SetupSetting](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting) is not very verbose.

Is there a solution for this? My setup is a bit larger and I do the `#include` to avoid duplicate code for different editions of the same program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is this part of [`SetupSetting` documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=setupsetting):

> parses [Setup] section in **current translation**

Where the ["current translation" is defined](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=current-translation) as:

> refers to current output of ISPP, the translated (preprocessed) part of the script **up to the point (or line) which ISPP is currently processing**.

At the point of your `#include`, the `AppId` is not defined yet.

A solution is to move the `#include` below the `Setup` section:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{87E1AD40-F32B-4EF7-A2FF-5B508814068A}
...

#include "include.iss"
```

---

Or, as you have found yourself, use a preprocessor variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to workaround the issue by defining a pre-processor value for the AppId, e.g. AppGUID, and then use it instead:

test.iss

```
#define AppGUID "{87E1AD40-F32B-4EF7-A2FF-5B508814068A}"
#include "include.iss"

[Setup]
AppId={{#AppGUID}
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName=My Program
```

include.iss

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  S := '{#AppGUID}';
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```